# Grab similar companies based on primary categories

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `Company` model and `PrimaryCategory` model. A company has_and_ belongs_to_many primary categories and a primary category has_and_belongs_to_many companies. When I visit a company show page, I want to grab 5 other companies that have the same primary category as the company in the show view.

In my company controller in the Show action

```
def show
  @primary_category = @company.primary_categories
  @companies = Company.where(primary_categories: @primary_category).limit(5)
end
```

And I have a set_company before_action method that grabs the company before rendering the view.

The error I receive is

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column companies.primary_category_id does not exist
```

What is the right query command to grab information from an association?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @coder_nick  what is "@primary_category" value? have you checked? are asking the where statement the right question? are you passing an ID?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. I looked further into it further and found this solution worked: @companies = Company.includes(:primary_categories).where(primary_categories: { id: @primary_category.id}).limit(5)